# Javascript to Disable/Enable form fields

Tags: javascript

I want this script to disable date fields when the page loads, then enable/disable depending on the drop down field. The script simply isnt doing anything, was wondering if anyone can see what I am doing wrong.

```
    <head>
    function formdisable(){
    var myTextField = document.getElementById('searchby');
if(myTextField.value = "agencyname")
    document.searchform.Date1.disabled=true
    document.searchform.Date2.disabled=true
    document.searchform.agencyname.disabled=false
else
    document.searchform.Date1.disabled=false
    document.searchform.Date2.disabled=false
    document.searchform.agencyname.disabled=true
    }
    onload = start;
    </script>
    </head>
    <table>
    <form id="searchform" name="searchform"> 
    <tr>
    <td>Search Term: </td><td><input tabindex="1" type="text" name="search" id="search1"        value=""  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Search By:</td><td><select size="1"  id="searchby" name="searchby" onclick="formdisable()" tabindex="2">
<option value="agencyname">Agency Name</option>
<option value="daterange">Date Range</option>
    </select></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Beginning Date: </td><td><input  id="Date1" name="Date1" size="10"   maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $_GET['Date1']?>"/> </td><td>Ending Date: </td><td><input   id="Date2" name="Date2" size="10" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $_GET['Date2'];?>" />          </td></tr>
   <input type="hidden" id="wildcard" value="= 'Approved'" />  
   <input type="hidden" id="repid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['REPID']; ?>" />  
   <tr><td><input tabindex="3" type='button' onclick='searchAgency()' name="searchsub"  value='Search' /></td></tr></td>
   </tr>
   </form>
   </table>
```

Comment: It is essential to use the Firebug addon for Firefox, or the Chrome/Safari developer tools, or IE8/9 Developer tools (F12). The console would catch the syntax error at `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right away, I see missing `{}` in your `if/else`, and an assignment `=` where an equality `==` belongs:

```
if(myTextField.value = "agencyname")
    document.searchform.Date1.disabled=true
    document.searchform.Date2.disabled=true
    document.searchform.agencyname.disabled=false
else
    document.searchform.Date1.disabled=false
    document.searchform.Date2.disabled=false
    document.searchform.agencyname.disabled=true
```

Should probably be:

```
<script type='text/javascript>
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Forgot the opening script tag
```

Then...

```
if(myTextField.value == "agencyname") {
    //-------------^^^^^^^
    // ==, not =
    document.searchform.Date1.disabled=true;
    // Please manually insert semicolons--^^^
    document.searchform.Date2.disabled=true;
    document.searchform.agencyname.disabled=false;
}
else {
    document.searchform.Date1.disabled=false;
    document.searchform.Date2.disabled=false;
    document.searchform.agencyname.disabled=true;
}
```

In your original version, you were assigning `agencyname` to `myTextField.value` inside the `if()` condition.  Followed by that was a mess of partially executed code.  The assignment would succeed, and then the first (and only the first) subsequent statement would execute as part of the `if()` block.  The next two would execute before coming to a syntax error on the `else`.

You are relying on automatic semicolon insertion, which is a dangerous (mis-)feature of the JavaScript language when used recklessly. Please always terminate your statements with `;`

Comment: @savagenoob Just noticed you're also missing the opening `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 6 ; two } and one { also you need to use == instead of =.

You should read a [getting started tutorial](http://javascript.about.com/od/learnjavascript/a/tut00.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I got to agree with Michael but you also missed  opening tag